# How to make a 'forward' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, jqtouch

I a make the 'back' button, which I can use to add `back` to the `className`.

However, I want to make a `forward` button, that slide right when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to do some CSS styling of your own, however

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <a class="button back" href="#">Home</a>
    <a id="someId" class="button slide listButton" href="#targetPage">List</a>
</div>
```

will work with bit of CSS... (i.e. you are going to get a rectangle button by default, you need a button that is a mirrored back button, look at the back button css on how to

Edit: I changed the href so that it automatically goes to the taget page.  Otherwise you will have to take out the "slide" class add an id, and then add some handler in the javascript:

```
 $('#someId').tap(function(){ jQT.goTo('targetPage'); });
```

Comment: You may also need to implement the behaviour of listButton elements with javascript, e.g. $('.listButton').live('tap', function(){...}).